# Capture a custom image size with the camera or crop it

Tags: android, android-camera, ocr, crop

Am working on OCR system which is requiring to capture image and do OCR, i  would like to capture part of the paper (Exact where intended text is) or crop captured image before passing it to OCR processing for better results.

I tried bellow code but i can't make it to what am trying to archive as am beginner to android java

```
private void startCameraActivity() {
    try {
        String IMGS_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/ocr/imgs";
        prepareDirectory(IMGS_PATH);

        String img_path = IMGS_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";

        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(img_path));

        final Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

        takePictureIntent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("outputY", 100);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent data) {
    //making photo
    if (requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        doOCR();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: Image was not obtained.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void doOCR() {
    prepareTesseract();
    startOCR(outputFileUri);
}
```

Am someone help me out here, Thanks.

**NOTE**

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
takePictureIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
takePictureIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
takePictureIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

takePictureIntent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
takePictureIntent.putExtra("outputY", 100);
```

After clearning my cache i noted the above code is opening **complete action with** apps which can crop image and everything is fine now.

Thanks.

Comment: `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not have those extras. There is no requirement for any camera app to honor those extras. Use [an image cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) to allow the user to crop an image, such as after they have taken the photo.

Comment: Thanks, for the link is very useful.

Comment: So your question is answered? Please add your answer as an answer, not as an edit to the original question.